# I m facing an issue related to ngx-spinner

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

ERROR in : 'ngx-spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-spinner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

Comment: Import its module into your own module.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import ngx-spinner module in your module.

```
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
```

[Read more here.](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner)

Comment: I have already import it in app.module.ts file.                                                                             
If i uninstall ngx-spinner plugin then also i am getting this same error

Comment: Check your project if you are using it elsewhere?

Comment: I used to have the same issue, if you use the spinner in a lazy loaded feature's module,  import thae spinner module in the lazy loaded module not only in app.module, or put in in a shared module then impot it in every the modules where you want to use the spinner

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `SharedModule`, then you must export the `NgxSpinnerModule`,
this will work:

`shared.module.ts`:

```
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [NgxSpinnerModule],
  exports: [NgxSpinnerModule],
  providers: [...]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [SharedModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**In app.module.ts :**

```
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
```

then add the NgxSpinnerModule and Schema.

```
imports: [.....,NgxSpinnerModule ],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
exports:[NgxSpinnerModule]
```

Add the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Repeat the same if you have any other shared modules

import NgxSpinnerService to the component(.ts) where you want to use the spinner.

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
```

Add the constructor too,

```
constructor(private spinner : NgxSpinnerService)
```

then add `this.spinner.show()` to enable the spinner and `this.spinner.hide()` to disable the spinner.

In HTML file :

add `<ngx-spinner type="ball-spin-clockwise"></ngx-spinner>`